# Angularjs value not displaying

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to integrate Xeditable table. But when I code something like below its not diplaying any value.

JS code

```
app.controller('XeditableCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', '$http','editableOptions','editableThemes', 
  function($scope, $filter, $http,editableOptions,editableThemes){
    editableThemes.bs3.inputClass = 'input-sm';
    editableThemes.bs3.buttonsClass = 'btn-sm';
    editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
    $scope.test = 'janan';
  }]);
```

HTML code

```
<div class="wrapper-md" ng-controller="XeditableCtrl">
  <h4>Test Value is </h4>
 {{ test }}      
</div>
```

Comment: Did you include ng-app in your markup? Can you post your whole code. That would be a great help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working  example her : http://plnkr.co/edit/Sez91V5vsWVhCEPl7rBk?p=preview

i remove the dependency for 'editableOptions','editableThemes' because i don't have ther code.

## JS

```
angular.module('ngAppListDemo', []).
controller('XeditableCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', '$http', 
  function($scope, $filter, $http){
    //editableThemes.bs3.inputClass = 'input-sm';
    //editableThemes.bs3.buttonsClass = 'btn-sm';
    //editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
    $scope.test = 'janan';
  }]);
```

### HTML

```
  <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ngAppListDemo">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>


<div class="wrapper-md" ng-controller="XeditableCtrl">
  <h4>Test Value is </h4>
 {{ test }}      
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some error occurred before reaching $sscope.test = 'janan'. I have tried your example by removing editableoption and editablethemes code and it worked fine.

`app.controller('XeditableCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', '$http', 
  function($scope, $filter, $http,){
    $scope.test = 'janan';
  }]);`

Use console tab of inspect element to check error occurred. Hope this helps.